# How do I delete an old boot option that doesn't show in bcdedit?

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

I converted my ssd from MBR to GPT. Now in the BIOS I have 2 boot options with the same name, which is "SSD name Boot Manager". Booting into the first boot option doesn't work but the 2nd one does. How do I delete the first one? I tried using bcdedit in cmd but it only shows 2 boot options, which are Windows Boot Manager and Windows Boot Loader.